# Disable manual editing of application.exe.config file

Tags: c#, settings

I made a program with permission settings, so that the leader can say what others can do and what they can't. But that can be edited manually in the startupfolder, by editing the MyApplication.exe.config. So that anyone can get all permissions. How can i disable that file or make it impossible to edit?

I am using .NET Framework 4.5, my compiler is visual studio 2012 and i am programming in C#.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

PS. If i'm unclear somewhere, or if you need more information then just explain what's needed.

EDIT: I want to install the program on serval computers.

Comment: Don't give the user an admin account.  If he has one then he can do *anything* with his machine.

Answer (score 3):

there are ways to encrypt sections of the app.config file so that if opened with a text editor it won't be possible to read its content, would that help? see the discussion here for some links further down.... [Encrypting the app.config file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08153cf1-41b6-4472-875b-803f0845a4e1/encrypting-the-appconfig-file)

or you can also decrypt the appSettings or other settings from your code and generate encrypted settings at compile time. It depends on how often and how you plan to edit those settings.

sure there are also other ways and possibly also file access security methods but it depends on your network as well, if you want to exclude a group of people from editing that file in your domain, you could give them only read access but what happens if they copy the whole application folder to another location and edit the config file in the new location?

Comment: thanks for the input but the link didnt realy get me any further.